# Atom weight in SI units

Tags: curated-data, units, chemistry

In chemistry is very common to use the units grams/mol for the atomic weight, so the mass of one atom (of Tin, for example) is calculated as :

massOfOneAtom = (0.11871 (Kg/mol))/(AvogadroConstant (1/mol))= 1.97123*10^-25 Kg

When I try to do that with Mathematica, the Output is:

```
ma = ElementData["Tin", "AtomicWeight"]
Na = Quantity["AvogadroConstant"]

massOfOneAtom = ma/Na

118.710u

1 Avogadro constant

118.710 u/Avogadro constant
```

How can I express this calculation to have a numeric result of the mass of one atom in standard SI units?

Comment: Quite ugly: `UnitConvert[ElementData["Tin", "AtomicWeight"], "Grams"] UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "AvogadroConstant"]]`

Comment: Thank you very much. Very useful answer:

I just defined the gmol[element_] function as :
gmol[element_] := 
 UnitConvert[ElementData[element, "AtomicWeight"], "Grams"]*
  UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "AvogadroConstant"]]
Then I use gmol["Tin"] with this result:
118.710 g/mol

Answer (score 3):

Since you ask *"How can I express this calculation to have a numeric result ..."*

```
myQ = Quantity["AvogadroConstant"] Quantity[1, "Mol"]
```

> 6.022141*10^23

```
myM = QuantityMagnitude[ElementData["Tin", "AtomicWeight"]]
```

> 118.710

```
myM/myQ
```

> 1.97123*10^-22

Have a test on Board:

```
UnitConvert[ElementData["Tin", "AtomicWeight"], "Grams"]
```

> 1.97123*10^-22 g

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the mass of one tin atom as the OP suggests, it is probably more convenient to obtain the [Molar Mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_mass), and then divide by the [Avogadro constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant).

```
ElementData["Tin", "MolarMass"] / Quantity["AvogadroConstant"] // UnitConvert
```

> 1.97123 × 10<sup>-25</sup> kg

The default output for `MolarMass` is (conveniently) g.mol<sup>-1</sup> (rather than Kg.mol<sup>-1</sup>)

ElementData["Tin", "MolarMass"]

> 118.710g/mol

*Mathematica* (apparently) makes no distinction between `AtomicWeight` and `AtomicMass` ([IUPAC discussion](https://www.iupac.org/publications/pac/1992/pdf/6410x1535.pdf)), (the default output (v11) is [unified atomic mass units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_atomic_mass_unit), u), and the result the OP requires may also be obtained as follows:

```
ElementData["Tin", #] & /@ {"AtomicWeight",  "AtomicMass"} // UnitConvert
```

> {1.97123 × 10<sup>-25</sup> kg, 1.97123 × 10<sup>-25</sup> kg}

Although the default output for `MolarMass` is g.mol<sup>-1</sup>, *Mathematica* is clever enough to evaluate the following as `true`

```
(ElementData["Tin", "MolarMass"]/Quantity["AvogadroConstant"]) == 
ElementData["Tin", "AtomicWeight"]
```

> True

Comment: I think we had a discussion on this subject before... :)

Comment: @ J.M. True! ... :)